# Conditional formatting of columns of a dataframe based on values from another dataframe Streamlit

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting, streamlit

I've got two dataframes, same number of rows, only second one had less columns and it derives some values from columns which are later redundant and eleiminated.
I created some sample data and I will explain how the logic works.
My first main dataframe is like this:
[image]

Starting from this one, I created the derived dataframe, which only retains A1, B1, A2, B2, A3 and B3 columns. But, instead of 1 and 2 values, these are replaced with values from corresponding Size columns. SO the result will be like this:
[image]

I am using streamlit to display the second dataframe and I need to format the A1, B2 ... B3 columns with a font color following this logic: for example A1 column values will be colored green if value in main dataframe is 2, otherwise red. We ignore empty items, as these will remain empty. Same logic for other columns B1, A2, B2, A3 and B3. So basically it's a conditioning formatting where formatting in a dataframe is based on values from columns from another dataframe.

I have this piece of code writen, but it doesn't do what I expect, everything is colored in red, as comparrison seems to be done against percentage values, from small dataframe, instead of values from the big dataframe:

```
 def color_cells(val):
        return 'color:green;' if val == 2 else 'color:red;'

df_style = df_patterns_all.style.map(color_cells, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:, ['A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'B2', 'A3', 'B3']])

st.dataframe(
    df_patterns_display_all.style.map(background_color).map(font_color).map(font_bold)
                                 .use(df_style.export())
                                 .format(mapper), width=900)
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?